# When using Titanium (Appcelerator Studio) with xcode 8, how do I turn ON "automatically manage signing"?

Tags: appcelerator, xcode8, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I'm a long-time Titanium developer who recently upgraded to xcode8.  Afterwards, I could not build to my iOS device.  I was getting an error about my provisioning profile being managed but the signing of my app requires a manual provisioning profile.  The only way I could figure out to move past the error was to create a manual provisioning profile.  Instead, I'd like to turn ON "automatically manage signing" but I cannot figure out how to do this in Appcelerator Studio.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic code-signing is not supported by Titanium, yet, and you should create your provisioning profiles in the [iOS Dev-Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) until it is officially supported.

See [TIMOB-24008](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24008) for more information.